# Sum of Count in SQL Server BI

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, business-intelligence, reportbuilder

Am developing a report using the SQL Server BI Development Studio, when I try to create a function to sum the counts for StudentID, I get an error "Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other aggregate functions"

The following is the expression am using:-
=Sum(Count(Fields!StudentID.Value))

How can I perform such a calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
;With CountIds AS
(
SELECT COUNT(Fields!StudentID.Value) AS CountOfId FROM Table ... 
)
SELECT Sum(CountOfId)
FROM CountIds
```

The "With" gives you the COUNT with the conditions that you want. Then you SUM it.

But I'm not quite sure the query returns what you want.. (Because when I test the query, it gives me the same result that a COUNT on all the table..) I think want you want to know is "How many Count you have".

If so, I would do it that way instead.

```
;With CountId AS
(
SELECT COUNT(Fields!StudentID.Value) AS CountOfId FROM Table ... 
)
SELECT TOP 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CountOfId)
FROM CountIds
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Or simply:

```
;With CountId AS
(
SELECT COUNT(Fields!StudentID.Value) AS CountOfId FROM Table ... 
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CountIds
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Your response is appropriate as an SQL statement. The key trouble I have is how to apply it as a function (expression) in the SQL Server Reporting Service interface. The option only accepts function that start with an "=" sign and not an SQL statement.